# Wrong prefix in Bundle-Id, should be Team Id

Tags: xcode

I am updating an old app (Objective-C) that I released quite a few years ago. I have not touched the app since then and do not fully remember how to do XCODE things as I have changed platform to Unity.

The problem I have is that the application identifier have the wrong prefix and I do not know how to fix that. I have been google the problem but still not ab le to fix it. Anyone here that can give me some advises?

Message that I get when uploading:

[image]

More details:
[image: , should have the team id,]

Answer (score 0):

This error probably means that you have signed the app with the wrong Provisioning Profile. Make sure to select the correct one inside Xcode -> Signing & Capabilities

Anyway as indicated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1726/_index.html), it is a warning, not an error

> Note: This is a warning, not an error. You have the option of proceeding with the submission regardless of this warning, however this document should be used to determine whether you can safely ignore it.

This means, that you might not have access to the Keychain because you are signing with a different ID

This is expected with *old* apps: [read here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2311/_index.html)